# AWS AUTH0 DELEGATION ERROR Missing principal parameter (invalid_request)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, auth0, delegation, principal

**While trying to fetch a delegation token from Auth0 to access S3 bucket on AWS I am getting this error:**

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing principal parameter"
}
```

**Here is the body of the request:**

```
{ 
    "client_id": "HIDDEN CLIENT ID",
    "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    "id_token": "HIDDEN ID TOKEN",
    "target": "HIDDEN TARGET",
    "api_type": "aws",
    "role": "HIDDEN ROLE ARN"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be other solutions but how I got it to work was to:

```
Replace,
         "api_type": "aws"
With: 
         "api_type": "aws:s3"
OR:
         "api_type": "aws:x" (where x is any AWS service code that you are trying to access!)
```